# Upgrading a graphics card

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

Is it possible for me to upgrade my laptop's graphics card in my scenario?
I understand it is possible for some laptop graphics cards to be upgraded, but is it possible for my laptop specifically?

I have:

```
-Samsung NP700G7C laptop    
-NVIDIA GeForce GTX 675M| TDP 100 W | Bus Interface MXM-B 3.0
```

Possible upgrades:

```
-NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780M
-GeForce GTX 970M
```

Both have Bus Interface MXM-B 3.0
Although TDP is higher around 122W

Comment: The 980M has a 122W TDP. The 970M has a 100W TDP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A MXM V3.0 card can be replaced, that is true.
Carefull: They come in 2 formfactors, A and B and the B modules might not fit if your current is an A.

But your laptop can only handle a GPU with a TDP of 75W with it's cooling (so says the service manual) and with the 675M it is already running on the edge. It gets bloody hot already.

Any faster GPU will also have a higher TDP. You WILL overheat the laptop.

So, possible? YES
Usable? NO

In other words: You will be wasting your money on such an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It seems quite possible, however I would recommend choosing an upgrade with the same or closest TDP, to avoid issues.

Comment: @Rob177 no prob